# Почему цикл не возобновляет работу? (программа "светофор")

Tags: java, циклы

Цель: 
создать светофор с выводом в консоль каждую секунду, автоматически начинает гореть с красного - горит с интервалом в секунду (красный - 2сек, желтый - 4сек, зеленый - 3секи), + продумать что-то чтобы нажатием кнопки на клавиатуре его можно было остановить, и потом продолжить. 
На данном моменте код работает, светофор можно остановить и продолжить (с момента остановки) НО почему-то второй раз я уже не могу остановить его. Почему? Вот код который я "наворотил":

TrafficLight  - сам цикл вывода:

```
public class TrafficLight implements Runnable{  
        long a= System.currentTimeMillis();
        long helper = a;
        long b = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        boolean cycle = true;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("точка входа - "+a); 
            do{                 
                    b = System.currentTimeMillis(); //новая точка 
                if (b == a + 1000){
                    ++counter;
                    if (counter >= 0 && counter <=2){
                        System.out.println("     красный  - " + b + " " + counter);
                    } else if (counter >=3 && counter <=6){
                        System.out.println("     желтый  - " + b + " " + counter);
                    } else if (counter >=7 && counter <=9){
                        System.out.println("     зеленй  - " + b + " " + counter);
                        if(counter == 9){
                            counter = 0;
                        }
                    } 
                    a = b;                          
                }                       
            } while (cycle); 
        } //конец метода run()

}
```

И второй класс TrafficLightGUI  - с помощью него останавливаю цикл из 1го класса:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TrafficLightGUI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TrafficLight tx1 = new TrafficLight(); //создали объект класса с раном
        Thread th1 = new Thread(tx1); // создали объект потока на базе класса с раном
        th1.start();

        // окно создаю без размеров + убираю его видимость, ТАК как незнаю как реалтзовать 
        // KeyListener без еб$#ого окна
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Заголовок окна"); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

        frame.setSize(0, 0); // размер окна
        frame.setUndecorated(true); //строка для setOpacity(0.1f);
        frame.setOpacity(0.1f); // прозрачность

        Container content = frame.getContentPane();
        JButton button = new JButton("Progress");   
        button.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { 
                if (e.getKeyChar() == 's') { //если нажать 's' - прога должна прекратить выводить в консоль
                    tx1.cycle = false; 
                } else if(e.getKeyChar() == 'd'){ //если нажать 'd' - продолжить выводить на консоль
                    tx1.cycle = true;
                    tx1.a = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
                    //ThreadExperement.a = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    tx1.run();      
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "ткнули "); //любая другая кнопка (проверка Листенера)
                }
            }
        });
        content.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }
}
```

Хотел бы услышать Ваши советы, а лучше реализованные решения действительно правильными и эффективными способами, в виде вашего кода

Answer (score 1):

Не срабатывает потому, что при остановке и последующем запуске Вы используете МЕТОД tx1.run(), и поток больше таковым не является, просто выполняется бесконечной цикл в основном потоке.
Вот мой пример кода:

class TrafficLight

```
@Override
public void run() {
    do{
        ...
    } while (cycle);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    run();

} //конец метода run()
```

А в классе TrafficLightGUI в слушателе просто убираем строку tx1.run();.

По поводу вынужденного применения окна: как вариант навскидку, попробуйте назначить экшены светофора с применением System.in в коде, он умеет ждать, как и окно. Раз уж всё равно приложение консольное)

Comment: Спасибо все получилось. Прога работает как хотел. Скажите, а есть ли способ написать тоже самое, только лучше?) каким еще методом Вы бы решили такую задачу?

Comment: Весьма рад, что смог помочь, не зря учился)

Comment: Лично я бы сделал так, что бы при нажатии "s" поток полностью останавливался с сохранением последнего сигнала светофора и временем, прошедшим после смены, а на "d" - стартовал новый и "подхватывал" сессию предыдущего по этим двум переменным, переданным, к примеру, через конструктор. Данный способ позволит полностью разгрузить ядро, выделенное на поток, но возникнет необходимость каждый раз создавать новый.